# Can't able to open collabnet merge wizard in eclipse

Tags: android, merge, client, collabnet

I had installed "Collabnet Merge Client" in eclipse by the following link Subclipse 1.8.x Update Site - http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.8.x. By right clicking the project Team->Merge    eclipse default Merge wizard is opening but "Collabnet Merge Client" wizard is not open. `How to open "Collabnet Merge Client" wizard`. Advance thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had installed both `Subversive and Subclipse SVN` in eclipse, so it accessed subversive SVN while clicking Team->Merge. Solution is either `"Uninstall Subversive SVN (Chances for eclipse crash)"` or `"Download a new eclipse and install Subclipse Plugin for SVN (Best Solution worked for me)"`

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can go in Eclipse preference to choose which Merge tool to use :
`TEAM>SVN>DIFF/MERGE` --> Merge Implementation